# I want to get voltage gain in BJT by using LTspice

Tags: bjt, ltspice

This is the task that I want to solve using LTspice:

[image]

I solved the problem like this:

[image]

But when I did this in LTspice, something`s different:

[image]

Please, someone tell me what the problem is and share a solution. I want to get '-100' voltage gain.

Comment: You have 5V across each of your 10K resistors in figure [3].  What does that say about the collector current of your BJT?

Comment: Are you sure that the transistor is biased such that Ic = 0.5 mA?

Comment: I'll give one more hint.  Your BJT's base node is floating.  It's not enough to simply put a label there like you did with the output node.  You actually need something else there.