# I`m getting into a trouble with ltspice to get a voltage gain of BJT(NPN)

Tags: bjt, ltspice

[image]

The picture above is the problem. I solved the problem like bellow

[image]

I tested this circuit by ltspice expecting that voltage gain shows 0.09615.

[image]

But the result of Vout was just flat like dc output. And I added V1=0.7563[V] because the problem 4.58 said dc collector current is 0.5[mA] (only to set the Ic value).

[image]

The solution of the book is different from my way and the result of ltspice is also different. please someone share give me some tips!

Comment: Please add fig.4.33A also. "*Biased at a collector current of...*". But the biasing circuit is not visible in the figure. This seems to be an *exact* duplicate of another question asked here in the last two weeks  see if that question has an answer.

Comment: Seems to be a [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/566912/238590). But it ha no answer there I think.

Comment: You're applying KCL at the emitter assuming it is not connected, but the emitter is **grounded** so you also need to take that into account. That will complicate things. It is much easier to realise that ic = gm*Vz and use that, like is done under "4.57". Your **simulation cannot work** as your biasing source V1 overrules any voltage that signal source V5 tries to put on the base. V1 "wins" so there will be **ZERO** signal on the base. You need to remove C1 and put V1 and V5 in series so that at the base you get V1 (bias) + V5 (signal). Also you should learn to use an AC analysis for this.

Comment: vi is not affected by r\$_\pi\$ so that term should not be in the gain equation. In your simulation, you have shorted the base with your bias source. You can either stack it on top of the input voltage  (or add a bias voltage to the AC input with a single voltage source) or use a current source to bias the transistor (which is high impedance).

Comment: The dynamic emitter resistance in a transistor is 26/emitter mA current which is 26/0.5= 52 ohms. The total load is 5k ohms then the gain is 5k/52= 96.2 times.

Comment: Besides the other comments, probing after `C3` is pretty pointless without a DC path to ground (i.e. some sort of resistor).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your problem with the simulation is the connection of V1 to the base:

[image]

V1 has no output impedance so V5 has no influence on the base voltage.

Ways to remedy this are:

1. Add a resistor between V1+ and the transistor's base.
2. Specify the series resistance in the settings dialog for V1, e.g.:

[image]

3. Specify V1 to be a sine wave with a DC offset.

Comment: "*V1 has no output impedance*" -- did you mean zero resistance?

Comment: Yes - no (or zero) output impedance or no series resistance are two equivalent descriptions